# Laravel: Which performance is faster?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

For example:

I have 100 data in table 1, the columns are: column 1, column 2, type

Now in my view, I have 3 portions. First portion i want to display the type 0, 2nd portion is type 1 and 3rd portion is type 3

##### First Approach

In my controller, I have 1 variable where it will fetch all the data and now in my view I used 3 foreach to separate the 3 types

For example:

##### In controller

```
$all_portions = Model::get();
```

##### View

```
foreach($all_portions as $portion)
{
  if($portion->type == 0)
  {
  }
}

foreach($all_portions as $portion)
{
  if($portion->type == 1)
  {
  }
}
```

#### Second approach

In my controller, I have 3 variables where it will fetch the designated type

For example

##### In controller

```
$portion_one = Model::where('type',0) etc etc.
```

##### In view

```
foreach($portion_ones as $portion_one)
{
  //display values
}
```

Question: Which performance is better? First or Second?

Comment: did you require some kind of parameter to filter the data on each 3 different portion? if yes, i'd suggest to go with the second approach. the overhead of starting another query is negligible if each portion has independent pagination or filtering.

Comment: why not there is one table in the view and there you define a column named type?

Comment: For only 100 data in the table, I think they're same. But with thousands or millions data, you should use the method 2, with creating index on 'type' column.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. First, is your type column indexed or not? How much data do you have on that table?

But for a general rule, if you have millions of data and you indexed it, it will be faster than getting all the data and then iterating them one by one.

iterating one by one will cost you n times, indexed one will only cost you log n because it is indexed by a binary tree.

for 100 data, I'm not sure, just check it with time logging I guess.

Comment: So youre saying is none of the above?

Comment: I am not testing it for 100 data, but for general use, I will prefer to index the column and query it one by one. In any case, your database will grow big anyway. So don't iterate it one by one if you have a choice